# Leaflet + GeoServer + British National Grid

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have followed along some examples and was able to display BNG 27700 data nicely on the map, however now I want to perform getFeatureInfo function on click. Again the code I used is as below:

```
var BBOX=map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
var WIDTH=map.getSize().x;
var HEIGHT=map.getSize().y;
var X=map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
var Y=map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
var SRS=map.options.crs.code;
var URL="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/OSM/wms?INFO_FORMAT=application/json&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH="+ WIDTH+"&HEIGHT="+HEIGHT+"&X="+X+"&Y="+Y+"&BBOX="+BBOX+"&SRS"+SRS+"&LAYERS=OSM:BuildingBoundaries&QUERY_LAYERS=OSM:BuildingBoundaries";`
```

However no feature is returned. If I make use of sample data from Geoserver in leaflet, the click event works perfectly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the OSM data reprojected to BNG27700? If not it will be  EPSG:4326, aka WGS84 http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Projection

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using Proj4js for setting the CRS on the map itself. Doing so results all BNG 27700 data (data itself is in 27700 and declared as 27700 SRS in geoserver)  align correctly. The issue is with the click event. Is there any way to enable getfeatureinfo on custom projection. It might be the case that the click event is translating to EPSG:4326 rather then BNG27700. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a typo in &SRS"+SRS+. Is the equals sign missing also in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a line like `var crs = new L.Proj.CRS("EPSG:27700", ...);`
and you get the click event's `latlng = e.latlng`,
then you could do:

```
var WIDTH  = map.getSize(map.getZoom()).x;
var HEIGHT = map.getSize(map.getZoom()).y;
var X = map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, map.getZoom()).x;
var Y = map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, map.getZoom()).y;
```

and because `getBounds()` always returns `LatLngBounds`, whereas we need projected coordinates, you could do something like this to get the BBOX:

```
crs_bbox = L.bounds(crs.project(map.getBounds().getSouthWest()),
                    crs.project(map.getBounds().getNorthEast()));
```

Then your BBOX String would be:

```
crs_bbox_str = crs_bbox.min.x + ',' 
             + crs_bbox.min.y + ',' 
             + crs_bbox.max.x + ',' 
             + crs_bbox.max.y;
```

Comment: At the OP says in his comment 'The issue is with the click event.' not in the BBox

Comment: If your WMS service is using EPSG:27700, getBounds().toBBoxString() isn't compatible because it returns LatLng, so you wouldn't get meaningful results. I edited answer a bit to add clarity about how to get proper X,Y from the click event as I don't believe it's an issue with the click event, rather than with the data in the request